# How can I allow a User to set which friend will be able to see their data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

How can I allow a User to set which friend will be able to see their data?

Comment: Please have a look at the help center, especially where it was defined which questions can be asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: This will get you started https://www.udemy.com/swift-ios-chat-app-from-scratch-community-course/learn/#/

Answer (score 1):

There is no off-the-shelf answer to the this question, other than "design, develop, and deploy a server system that offers data sharing with users that are set up as a user's 'friends'."

It sounds to me like you have an original app idea that you will need to research and implement. If you are new to software development a multi-user client/server app is way, way, WAY beyond your abilities.

Come to think of it, the answer is really "hire a developer to help you come up with a functional design, technical spec, and implementation for your product idea."